# Android: TabLayout how set height = 0 programatically?

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout

**Here my `xml` of `TabLayout`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
         android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
         android:background="@android:color/white"
         android:minHeight="@dimen/standard_min_height_container"
         app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
         app:tabGravity="fill"
         app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
         app:tabMode="fixed"
         app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

<ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/customViewPager"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tabLayout"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/tabLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

How I can change **`TabLayout.android:layout_height = 0`** programatically.?

Comment: `How I can change TabLayout.android:layout_height = 0 programatically?` Why don't you perform `tablayout.setVisibility(View.GONE)` instead?

Comment: Because I need to show tab, but hide title

Comment: By making `TabLayout`'s height 0dp you no longer are going to see neither `TabLayout` nor `Tab`s. How are you planning to show a tab then?

Answer (score 1):

## Try this

- For `Constraint Layout` you have to change height and width by doing this simply

  ```
  tabLayout=(TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
      ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = 
    (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) tabLayout.getLayoutParams();
    // Changes the height and width to the specified *pixels*
      params.height = 500;
      params.width = 500;
      tabLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
  ```

---

## OutPut

[image]

Comment: Height NOT change.

Comment: @Alexei please try i've also paste an preview of `studio` and `output` of my `device`

Comment: Not help. Height is not change.   ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) tabLayout.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = 0;
            tabLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: put the `params.height =1;` instead of  `params.height =0;`

Comment: Yes. It's work!!! The question is: Why height = 0 not work, but height = 1 is work?

Comment: @Alexei `Happy to help you` bro

Comment: height 0 is not working because 0 indicate that you wish the height to be wrap_content or match_parent I don't remember which one exactly